# I cant seem to find how to redirect a trailing url

Tags: wordpress

I cant seem to find how to redirect a trailing url from:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=*
```

To:

```
www.domain.com/
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: remove the characters after first slash using substr and then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RewriteRule in apache configuration.  Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf. Then, in .htaccess file in root directory place the following

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=.*$
RewriteRule ^index\.php.*$ '' [R,L,QSD]
```

You have to use RewriteCond to parse the query string, then the RewriteRule uses the flag R to redirect, L to stop processing additional rules, and QSD avoids appending the query string onto the URI.  Since you are in web root, you can probably get away without using RewriteBase, but I used it for testing this code because I tested it with .htaccess in a subdirectory.  So for someone who wants to do something similar in a subdirectory, you would change the RewriteBase to /sub1/sub2/ to rewrite the url

```
www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=*
```

to

```
www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/
```

If you do not want the browser to report the change, then use the passthrough flag PT instead of redirect R.  There are other helpful flags for case-insensitve matching and more; you can view those [in apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).